# Unity 2D Error Nullreferenceexception: Object Reference Not Set To An Instance Of An Object C#

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, nullpointerexception

Hello I am new to coding in unity and i was trying to make the health bar go down when the player hits an object. When i use a `debug.log` it prints what i want it to print when it collides with the object however when i try to make the health go down when it hits the object it gives me this error

```
NullReferenceException: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
DamagePlayer.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D collision)
(at Assets/Scripts/DamagePlayer.cs:30)
```

here is my code.

My `Damage` class

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DamagePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BarScript bar;
    public int playerHealth = 100;
    int damage = 10;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        print(playerHealth);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {

       if(collision.collider.tag =="enemy")
        {

            Debug.Log("enemy");
            bar.math(damage);
        }
    }
}
```

Health `Bar` class

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BarScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float fillAmount;

    [SerializeField]
    private Image content;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        fillAmount = 1f;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        content.fillAmount = fillAmount;
    }

    public float math(float value)
    {
        return fillAmount =(value / 100);
    }

}
```

My `Player` class

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 300f;
    private float jump = 400f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Movement();
    }

    void Movement()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("d")){
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, rb.velocity.y);
        }else if (Input.GetKeyDown("a"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, rb.velocity.y);
        }else if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jump * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't create an `instance` of `BarScript` in `DamagePlayer`, that's  why this is creating problem.

Without instance you can't access member method of a `class`, you can use `static` to make that accessible by anyone. If it is **just for Player** then you can do that (Single-player), But it won't be so nice.

If you it's multi-player or you want do the same for enemy, then create `prefab` with both `script`, then `instantiate` or use `pooling`. Finally use `findGameobjectsWithTag` (not `findGameobjectWithTag`) and access those scripts, members and use their member methods.

Comment: when i creat an instance of BarScript in DamagePlayer it gives me this error "You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent(). Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:.ctor()
BarScript:.ctor()
DamagePlayer:.ctor() (at Assets/Scripts/DamagePlayer.cs:7)"

Comment: Create a `prefab` then put both script there, then access it using `GetComponent()<BarScript>`

Comment: Or, you can remove inheritance of `MonoBehaviour` from `BarScript` class & use that just to save damage amount, then update it from `HealthBar` script .